# Visual Studio C++ program doesn't work when I run without debugging but program runs fine when I run under debug?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I get this error while running this program without debugging but I don't get any error when I run it under debug.

---

```
Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: C:\Users\Desktop\130913\nevolver\Debug\nevolver.exe
 File: f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\fscanf.c
 Line: 52

Expression: (stream!=NULL)

For information on how your program can cause an assertion failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.

(Press Retry to debug the application)
```

---

Your help is much appriciated.

Comment: Can you post your code. It looks like `stream` isn't being set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably exactly what it says it is... You are apparently passing a NULL stream to `fscanf`.

You should examine your call to `fscanf`, and verify that the file-pointer you *think* you are reading from is not NULL.

Comment: I see. but why doesn't it happen when I run the same code under debug option?

Comment: Set a breakpoint at the line that's causing the assert, and look at your variables to understand why the assert is not firing.  It could be as simple as an uninitialized variable.